# Do humans in Naruto who are descendants of Otsutsuki have any extra abilities over pure humans?

Tags: naruto

At first I thought only humans who are descendants of the  Ōtsutsuki clan and other humans were the ones who had the ability to use chakra, but according to other answers here and in other pages apparently not.

Do humans in Naruto who are descendants of Otsutsuki have any extra abilities over pure humans, or are they just the same than pure humans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the descendends of Otsutsuki have extra abilities over normal humans/shinobis. They are in fact celestial beings that have travelled through dimensions seeking out worlds to plant [Ten-Tail saplings](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ten-Tails_(Seeds)) into. So, basically they are "gods" rather than normal human beings. Some of the abilities are given [in wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/%C5%8Ctsutsuki_Clan) (I am writing in points to reduce answer text):

- the Ōtsutsuki ingest the Chakra Fruits from God Trees, giving them their godlike power and longevity
- the Ōtsutsuki's had the ability to use what is known as "chakra" even before Hagoromo introduced it to humanity through the concept of ninshū.
- during the Fourth Shinobi World War, those with the Ten-Tails' chakra and Kaguya herself are impervious to almost every shinobi skill (only by using Hagoromo's Six Paths chakra that she is ultimately defeated).
- the Ōtsutsuki seem to remain unprecedentedly resilient even after they die (their soul wanders and manifest into other living beings)
- Their dojutsu had special abilities: their Byakugan can unlock Tenseigan where normal Byakugan users can't do it. They possessed Rinnegan which had godly powers.
- They are wielders of kekkei mora (advanced branch of jutsu unique to Kaguya Ōtsutsuki and her direct bloodline). Examples: [All-Killing Ash Bones](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/All-Killing_Ash_Bones), Kaguya's Byakugan

Comment: but supposedly most ninjas are descendants of Otsutsuki . So why dont we see these abilities, is it because they are mixed blood or something?

Comment: @Pablo Kind of yes. Although they are descendants and not members of direct bloodline, the jutsu nature and teachings changed clan-wise and that's why we don't exactly see the same jutsu or jutsu of godlike power levels among shinobis. For e.g. point 5. Their jutsu power levels are toned down due to limited human chakra reservoir. One can increase their chakra level and be a "god" by being a jinchuriki of 10-tails and attain rinnegan just like Madara did.